# Header row values not saving into array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here's my table:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QsP9zWOZHretwohq5e_2puQl0V0IMKHa-E-NJtBU4B4/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to put all values of the first row (the headers) into an array using this code:

```
for(let i=0;i<Cimiteri.length;i++)
  {
    var copySheet=as.getSheetByName('Date '+Cimiteri[i]);
    var ValoriA = copySheet.getRange(1,1,copySheet.getLastColumn()-1).getDisplayValues();
    for(let k=0;k<ValoriA.length-1;k++)
    {
      Logger.log(ValoriA[k]);
    }
```

The problem is, some of my headers are not beign saved inside the array, "date in ordine" and "20/09/2021 Occupati" are skipped and I can't figure out why.

Edit:
A cup of coffee later:

```
for(let i=0;i<Cimiteri.length;i++)
  {
    var copySheet=as.getSheetByName('Date '+Cimiteri[i]);
    var ValoriA = copySheet.getRange(1,1,1,copySheet.getLastColumn()-1).getDisplayValues().flat();
    for(let k=0;k<ValoriA.length-1;k++)
    {
      Logger.log(ValoriA[k]);
    }
```

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Comment: What is the range you're supposed to get here? `getRange(1,1,copySheet.getLastColumn()-1)`

Comment: @TheMaster I want to copy all non-blank cells of a row, starting from the cell A1

Comment: So the syntax is `getRange(row, column, #rows, # columns)`

Comment: @TheMaster yeah infact I figured this was the error after taking a break. thank you tho. I don't know if I can flag the post as solved

Answer (score 0):

Remove the loop and just look at:

```
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(copySheet.getRange(1,1,copySheet.getLastRow(),copySheet.getLastColumn() -1).getDisplayValues();)):
```

Comment: Thank you! The loop was just for debug, I don't really need to show values, but I'll use your method next time